# Add Custom Aspect Ratio to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Is there a Way to add a Custom Ratio like 21:9 to the Block-Editor.
I want to add my own Ratios to use it in the Crop-Tool. (Screenshot attached)

Extend the existing Ratios and remove unwanted Ratios.

- WordPress 6.2.2
- Custom Theme

Thanks a lot.

[Default Ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHvlF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, setting your own custom ratios are not supported - although it has [been previously suggested](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/38990#issuecomment-1396621330). The ratios are defined in [`DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_OPTIONS`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/ac57a486f961aa8bd51622d0c78fab28257fc49f/packages/block-editor/src/components/dimensions-tool/aspect-ratio-tool.js#L17) and the issue is being tracked via [ticket #48079](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/48079). It may appear in future releases of WordPress, as I agree it would be really useful option.

Comment: Think, i have to wait for the official implementation. Thanks @s-walsh